# Why are there multiple versions of windows-10 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see 13 different windows-10 tags. Some of them appear to be for specific applications such as windows-10-calendar-app, but that leaves many such as windows-10-v1511, windows-10-v1709, and windows-10s.

Why are there so many different tags for Windows 10? Are these really distinct versions?

Comment: My guess (I'm not really into Windows, so it's only a guess) is: at least some of these separate tags are justified because of "last version of Windows" (google it) and [Windows as a service](https://docs.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/deployment/update/waas-overview).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Are these really distinct versions?

Yes. These distinct version tags are used for questions that are specific to a particular version. Not all users have upgraded from older versions.

> [image]

Source [Windows 10 version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)

**What is Windows 10 S?**

> Windows 10 S is a specific configuration of Windows 10 Pro that offers a familiar, productive Windows experience that’s streamlined for security and performance. By exclusively using apps in the Microsoft Store and ensuring that you browse safely with Microsoft Edge, Windows 10 S keeps you running fast and secure day in and day out.
>
> For more information, please refer to [this page](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=847244).

Source [Windows 10 S FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4020089/windows-10-s-faq)

Comment: Ok, I thought that looked a little like Ubuntu versioning: YYMM, but I (almost embarrassingly) didn't realize Windows 10 has been out for 2 years now.

Answer (score 10):

> Why are there so many different tags for Windows 10?

Each Windows 10 feature update has introduced major changes to Windows 10 functionality.  There are things that are possible in earlier versions that are no longer possible and features that only exist in later versions.

> Are these really distinct versions?

Having made nearly all the tags for Windows 10 myself I know there isn’t actually 13 tags.

Comment: There are 13 tags starting with "windows-10" and, as I noted, I realize not all of them refer to the OS. My trouble was with knowing which ones do and why there were so many. Thank you for the info.

Comment: They might start with *Windows-10* but not all of them are Windows 10 tags.  *windows-10-calendar-app* is an application tag.